# settototalheight issue with empty lines

Tags: page-breaking, vertical-alignment, itemize, minipage, calculations

I am using `\settototalheight` to calculate the height of the text in order to use `needspace` correctly.

This is the code i am using :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e, calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{nolbreaks}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fonts
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{txfonts}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{217,217,217}  % Color used for highlighting
\definecolor{light-blue}{RGB}{0,175,236}    % Color for the footer

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Header and footer management.
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% clear any old style settings
\fancyhf{}

\fancyheadoffset{0in}
\headheight = 53pt

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\setmainfont{Calibri}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Defining the section style
\newcommand{\mysectionstyle}[1]{\colorbox{shadecolor}{\begin{tabular}{>{}p{\rectanglelength}}{\fontsize{13}{6}\selectfont\textbf{#1}}\end{tabular}}\vspace{6pt}}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\addtolength{\footskip}{0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{{\color{light-blue}%
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \hrule width\headwidth height\footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=1.5in,right=0.75in,bottom=1in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength{\rectanglelength}
\setlength{\rectanglelength}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\rectanglelength}{-6pt}

\newlength{\foo}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]


\settototalheight{\foo}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{11cm}>{\RaggedLeft}p{6.35cm}@{}}\fontsize{13}{6}\selectfont{LaTeX}&\textbf{2011 to 2012}\end{tabular}\\\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{11cm}>{\RaggedLeft}p{6.35cm}@{}}\textbf{Lead Programmer}&\textbf{}\end{tabular}%
\vspace{3pt}\begin{itemize}[parsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=2ex]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\end{itemize}%
\vspace{7pt}\textbf{End Title}\\\lipsum[1]

\vspace{10pt}\end{minipage}}
}
\needspace{\foo}{\setlength{\parskip}{4pt}

\mysectionstyle{Experiences}

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{11cm}>{\RaggedLeft}p{6.35cm}@{}}\fontsize{13}{6}\selectfont{LaTeX}&\textbf{2011 to 2012}\end{tabular}\\\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{11cm}>{\RaggedLeft}p{6.35cm}@{}}\textbf{Lead Programmer}&\textbf{}\end{tabular}%
\vspace{3pt}\begin{itemize}[parsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin=2ex]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\item \lipsum[1]\end{itemize}%
\vspace{7pt}\textbf{End Title}\\\lipsum[1]

\vspace{10pt}}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that settototalheight doesn't accept empty lines which is something i cannot control in my dynamic content. (This is a live text editor).

Is there a command or a package that accept empty lines to calculate the height of a text?
The real purpose of this is that each live text editor must not break into several pages or if it does, it starts at a new page then spread to the next ones (that's the reason of using needspace).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `calc` doesn't define `\settototalheight` (more precisely the helper macro `\@settodim`) as `\long`, so it doesn't accept empty lines in their argument.

We need to patch `\@settodim` to make it work. Put the following code in the preamble, after having loaded all packages:

```
%%% Patch calc
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\toks0=\expandafter{\@settodim{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \long\def\noexpand\@settodim##1##2##3{\the\toks0 }}\x
\makeatother
```

(See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39980/4427 for a similar answer where the same trick is used)

Comment: Thanks egreg. I'll check this out. It works on the example that i put, i'll try it in a real case scenario.

Answer (score 3):

The `adjustbox` environment from the package with the same name allows you to store the total height (and all other dimensions) of its content. Simply use the `minipage` key to allow for paragraphs in the content and at the end the `gooble` key to not insert the content at the current location.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newlength\mylength

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,gstore totalheight=\mylength,gobble}
Some text

with empty

lines
\end{adjustbox}

Total height is \the\mylength.

\end{document}
```

It's also possible to store the content into a savebox using the `gstore` key, however, you might want to have a vbox not a hbox here.

Comment: Which one is faster? The `\settototalheight` or the `adjustbox`? I suppose that the ajustbox doesn't need the `calc patch`. Which one is more flexible?

Comment: @Pete: Both store the content into a box and then store the total height of it into a length register. I would say `adjustbox` is more flexible if you want to adjust the contents even more before measuring the content (see the manual for all the features). The other method should be a little faster because it doesn't has to process the key=value syntax, but I don't think this matters much.